# how to get continously output using paramiko SSHClient

Tags: python, python-2.7, ssh, paramiko

I want to ssh to remote server and run some shell scripts(like scp or yum etc).

Everything went well except that I cant get continously stdout of sth like scp progress or yum download progress. The `f.read` will be blocked and nothing returns.

I guess paramiko may transfer fake stdout stream line by line but those progressive outputs do not output line separator but '\r'.

Is there anyway to solve this problem?

Here is what im doning now, where `ssh` is `paramiko.SSHClient()`

```
def read_buffer_line(f):
    line = ""
    while not f.channel.exit_status_ready():
        c = f.read(1)
        if c == '\n':
            yield line
            line = ''
        else:
            line += c
    yield line + f.read()

def ssh_run(ssh, cmd):
    stdin, stdout, sterr = ssh.exec_command(cmd, get_pty=True, bufsize=1)
    for l in read_buffer_line(stdout):
        print l
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`stdout.read(N)` returns only when N bytes has been read or it gets EOF. The `stdout.channel.recv(N)` returns as soon as there are new data available.

This works fine for me:

```
stdin, stdout, sterr = ssh.exec_command(cmd, get_pty=True)
while True:
    v = stdout.channel.recv(1024)
    if not v:
        break
    sys.stdout.write(v)
    sys.stdout.flush()
```